# Limit Field in Mongodb find() query not working

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a MongoDB database withe the following fields:

```
idSite: 3
parentHash: "zz"
siteDesc: "Second Site"
siteHash: "ab"
siteLevel: "1"
siteName: "Riotech"
siteType: "Company"

idSite: 4
parentHash: "zz"
siteDesc: "Oregon City Site"
siteHash: "aa"
siteLevel: "1"
siteName: "iTi"
siteType: "Company"
```

I want to write a query with a projection that limits the result to a dataset of one field, `parentHash`.  When I write the following query: `Sites.find({"siteHash":"aa"},{parentHash:1})`.

I get back the following results:

```
idSite: 4
parentHash: "zz"
siteDesc: "Oregon City Site"
siteHash: "aa"
siteLevel: "1"
siteName: "iTi"
siteType: "Company"
```

I have tried wrapping field names with double and single quotes, without quotes. I have tried defining the return status of all the other fields as false.  Everything returns the full document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be `Sites.find({"siteHash":"aa"},{fields: {parentHash:1}});`
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find

Comment: Thanks, it works.  I googled for a day and tried everything I found.  I obviously don't know how to ask Google the correct way.  Now, although it's working, I cannot extract the field I want from the object cursor that is being returned.  Seems silly to use a foreach for a single string var. Again, many Thanks,

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the entire docs, it's very well written and really comprehensive.