# Find query don't limit fields

Tags: mongodb

I got the following query:

```
query =  
{
    application: application,
    creationTime:{
        $gte: start_date.valueOf(),
        $lte: end_date.valueOf()
    }
},
{
    application: 1, 
    creationTime: 1,
    buildSystem: 1,
    _id:1
}

var ut_data = db.my_collection.find(query).sort({ _id: -1 }).forEach(function(doc) {print(doc.testStatus)})
```

Where I want to limit the fields in the result to application, creationTime and buildSystem, to not load the whole documents matching the condition.

Once I print testStatus, it seems like is also available, moreover all fields are available. How can I limit the fields in the result?

(I also tried: `{fields:{application: 1, creationTime: 1, buildSystem: 1, _id: 1}}` as proposed in [Limit Field in Mongodb find() query not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899114/limit-field-in-mongodb-find-query-not-working)
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing the two parameters of the query wrongly, so the second part was not considered, I fixed it like this:

```
query =  
[{
    application: application,
    creationTime:{
        $gte: start_date.valueOf(),
        $lte: end_date.valueOf()
    }
},
{
    _id: 1,
    application: 1, 
    creationTime: 1,
    buildSystem: 1,
}]
```

And then, passing each argument separately:

```
db.my_collection.find(query[0], query[1]).sort({ _id: -1 }).forEach(function(doc) {print(doc.testStatus)})
```

Or simply passing the query directly to the find method (w/o variables).